# Error: "Package not available" for a package that should be current

Tags: r

```
> install.packages("parallel")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘parallel’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)
```

Should I believe the warning message?  `Parallel` seems to have been recently active, as the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf) was written less than a year ago.  Has the project been abandoned?

Comment: You already have it. It comes with your R installation. No need to install it. `library(parallel)` works.

Comment: +1 @Joshua.  Indeed I do.  How could I have guessed that? (Or more directly, why was this question downvoted?)

Comment: @zkurtz You could have known that by running `installed.packages()` or checking the library in your R directory - but I think this was valid to ask here since the warning message is poorly written and suggests that the package is no longer available.

Comment: I don't necessarily think this a duplicate of the question I just posted, but BenBolker's answer there is a nicely comprehensive response to any confusion about base packages.